# Get div id by class name in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get id of a div with a class name 'heading' using jquery. After that I want to pass that id to the code behind and work with it.

After I click my link the JS function is invoked but I guess I've didn't do well job on the inside of it, cause I got null value for ar variable instead of "16".

Can someone help me with this problem? I'm totally new to jquery and I still don't know all of it's possibilities well.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="heading" id="16"><span>Nemanja Mosorinski</span><i>+</i></div>
<div class="details">
    <ul class="form">
        <li>
            <label>Name:</label><input type="text" class="in-text" /></li>
        <li>
            <label>Hours per week:</label><input type="text" class="in-text" /></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="form">
        <li>
            <label>Username:</label><input type="text" class="in-text" /></li>
        <li>
            <label>Email:</label><input type="text" class="in-text" /></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="form last">
        <li>
            <label>Status:</label><span class="radio"><label for="inactive">Inactive:</label><input type="radio" value="1" name="status" id="Radio5" /></span><span class="radio"><label for="active">Active:</label><input type="radio" value="2" name="status" id="Radio6" /></span></li>
        <li>
            <label>Role:</label><span class="radio"><label for="admin">Admin:</label><input type="radio" value="1" name="status" id="Radio7" /></span><span class="radio"><label for="worker">Worker:</label><input type="radio" value="2" name="status" id="Radio8" /></span></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="inner"><a href="javascript:;" id="updateMember" class="btn green">Save</a> <a href="javascript:;" class="btn red">Delete</a> <a href="javascript:;" class="btn orange">Reset Password</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#updateMember').click(function () {
            $('.heading').closest(function () {
                var ar = this.id;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'team-members.aspx/UpdateTeamMember',
                    data: "{'ID':'" + ar + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: fnsuccesscallback,
                    error: fnerrorcallback
                });
            });
        });
        function fnsuccesscallback(data) {
            alert(data.d);
        }
        function fnerrorcallback(result) {
            alert(result.statusText);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `id` shouldn't start with a number as a good practice, it will be problematic with css selectors if used.

Comment: What are you expecting `closest()` to do here???

Comment: @A.Wolff Well I was hoping to find closest div with that class name... I'm not sure what to use here... Maybe parent() would do better job?

Comment: id can start with a number. For html its fine, only problem is css, that dont like that.

Comment: @nemo_87 see George's answer then

Comment: @DerVampyr do you have any other suggestion where should I put it? like some other attribute that would be ok to start with number and which one I can get from JS?

Comment: @DerVampyr: Ahh yes.. I keep forgetting.. out of habit.. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: @abhitalks `id` may start with a number according to the HTML5 spec.

Comment: @nemo_87 There shouldn´t be a problem to access the element by that ID. jQuery is fine with Id´s that only contain numbers. Only problem is CSS. E.g. you can´t use ``#123 {display:none;}`` But if you dont need this you will be fine.

Comment: @George: Yes.. but CSS still has problems selecting numeric ids. [The ref here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#id-selectors) also still points to the old description only. [See the link 'identifiers' on that ref](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you mean to pass your entire functionality to `closest()`.

We can use the context of `#updateMember` to traverse (by means of [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)) to the nearest `.header` though, and get its `id` using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Also, the `data` property passed to `$.ajax()` accepts an Object Literal.

How about the following:

```
$(function () {
    $('#updateMember').click(function () {
        var ar = $(this).closest('.details').prev('.heading').prop('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'team-members.aspx/UpdateTeamMember',
            data: {"ID" : ar},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: fnsuccesscallback,
            error: fnerrorcallback
        });
    });
    function fnsuccesscallback(data) {
        alert(data.d);
    }
    function fnerrorcallback(result) {
        alert(result.statusText);
    }
});
```

Note: Please use the console for debugging (it's why it's there!) Using `alert()` will cause more confusion than it clears up.

Comment: Thanks for answering. When I try to run this code I still get null with alert...:(

Comment: @nemo_87 Are you sure you are getting a successful response from your server?

Comment: Well during debugging I don't go on error function. It goes straight to success function. When I put ar variable in alert after it's being created it gives me: undefined...

Comment: Use the console (**not alert**) for debugging! `console.log(data)` in your success function, see what you get.

Comment: I've tried that too, and it says [log returned] undefined, d property is null... @George

Comment: maybe the problem is that this HTML code is dynamically generated in the code behind, and it's passed with InnerHtml to another div.
The structure is really like: <div id="mainDiv" runat="server">Inside of this div goes HTML code from my post</div>
Could that be a problem? @George

Comment: @nemo_87 Whoops! I used the selector `.header` instead of `.heading` in `.prev()`. Update made.

Comment: Now I get error: Internal server error.
console.log says Invalid JSON primitive: ID.","StackTrace" and alert(ar) gives right vaule = 16
@George

Comment: I can't reproduce your error: http://jsfiddle.net/ax8t6mq9/1/ -- Sounds as though the error is server-side.

Comment: I've changed this: data: {ID: ar} to this: data: JSON.stringify({ "ID": ar }) as some other post suggested and it helped with an error, but still it gives me null in success function. Damn jquery hates me :( @George

Comment: The fiddle by @George works. the jsfiddle endpoint is /echo/json and it returns "not found". http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ax8t6mq9/2/ The problem is definitely server-side.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
data:"{'ID':'" + ar + "'}",
```

try this:

```
data: {"ID": ar },
```

and as mentioned here stingify it. Hope it helps

Comment: thanks for answering. I still have some problems, but I hope it will work :D